# How to add an attachment to mailto in Java

Tags: java, email, attachment, mailto

I am creating a text editor and I would like to add a share feature that would allow you to email your document. I need some help in finding a way to use the mailto with a variable. I use the string "saveName" as the path of the file to be sent. Here is what I have right now:

```
share.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        String mailData = "mailto:?subject=Document&attachment=" + saveName;
        System.out.println(mailData);
        try {
            desktop.mail(new URI(mailData));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    });
```

Can some one shed some light on how to do this? Help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JavaMail API. It will allow you to connect to a server and the send and receive mails.

Here is an example of JavaMail API with [Attachments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm).

This page has more comprehensive [working examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the Desktop class to launch he user's preferred mail client so they can send an email, but you want to have already attached a file.
A *mailto:* link may include (the start of) a body, and email [headers](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt)
including *to*, *cc*, *subject* and others...

Unfortunately, the `mailto:` URL type does ***not*** support attachments. Attachments are not headers and are not part of the body; they are a separate part of a multi-part mime message

The [Desktop class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail(java.net.URI)) javadoc mentions some of the fields available to `mail(URI)`, but has no mention of support for attachments.

I understand the desire to use the user's already-configured mail client, but to send an attachment you will have to handle the mail yourself and build the message out of [Part](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html)s